# How do you access an Amazon RDS instance from a chromebook?

Tags: ssh, amazon-rds, chromebook

I have accepted the "Chromebook challenge." So far, I have successfully ssh'ed into my new Google Compute Engine from ChromeOS's built in ssh terminal. But now I am faced with the task of connecting to an Amazon RDS (relational database service) instance that a consulting client has set up for me. I have found no tutorials how to do this. I don't know if I should be ssh'ing into the RDS, or what.

Has anyone else done this successfully?

Comment: You can't ssh to rds. You'll need some sort of database tools in your chromebook or use a web service that provides that sort of access

Comment: Thanks Frederick. I have produced a satisfactory solution, described in my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aha, so there is no way of ssh-ing to an RDS instance directly (Chromebook or otherwise), as Fredrick mentioned.

That said, I have accomplished all I needed by ssh-ing from my Chromebook into my Google Compute Engine, and then hopping from there to my RDS instance, using the standard:

```
me@myserver$mysql -h myrdsinstanceaddress -P 3306 -u root -p
```

So, the crux is that you have to ssh into some other server, and then work from there.

Answer (score 2):

From the [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html).

> Type the following command at a command prompt to connect to a DB instance using the MySQL utility. For the -h parameter, substitute the DNS name for your DB instance. For the -P parameter, substitute the port for your DB instance. Enter the master user password when prompted.

```
PROMPT> mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```